# security / server system logging of prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, security, logging, centos

I'm currently finalizing my application's security.

One question I have for you experts is whether there's a way for somebody taking control of my unix plateform, to extract the passwords from some kind of mysql logging?

My usual password transfers between php and mysql are done this way:

```
$sql = "CALL client_create(?, ...)";
$stmt = $cnx->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($hashpw, ...));
$cnx->commit();
```

There's no `autocommit` in my setup, if that changed anything.

So basically there must be some kind of redo-log or similar, right? What about that, should it be a concern? Should I flush it once in a while?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If they gain control of your system, they can just fetch the password coming over whatever line they want, and probably can just download your whole database. But yes, you have to protect binlogs like they hold passwords. Only throw them away if you don't care about disaster recovery.

Comment: is the innodb data clearly readable from the file system? I mean by that without actually connecting to mysql

Comment: Yes, and beyond that I assume you have a file on that file system that holds a password to that database. Your PHP code used to insert the data for instance (unless it's on another server). Or I just stop mysql, and set it to start with root with no password.

Comment: yes but the password of a user with no grants at all. Only the EXECUTE grant, which doesn't lead to any function that would return any password. What about the root with no password? Would it work? I have a password for my root mysql user.

Comment: [sure it works](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables)

Comment: That's a bad news. Thanks for your enlightment

Comment: You could make a summary of all this, I would consider it as an answer no problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're afraid of is absolutely possible. However, it shouldn't really be a concern. Let me explain:

MySQL currently uses a number of different types of logs:

1. [Binary Logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html) - These are for replication and get every single write-query written to it (in a reversible binary form). If you're doing replication, you need these logs.
2. [Query Logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html) - These are for debugging (usually). They are not often enabled on production (and they should be disabled).
3. [InnoDB Transaction Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-data-log-reconfiguration.html) - This is used for every write to allow for transactions to be ACID compliant (details are outside of the scope of this answer).
4. [Other Logs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-logs.html) - Nothing you need to wory about here (error logs, slow query logs, etc).

So the data is typically written at least to one log file, but possibly 3 (depending on server configuration).

But it's also written to disk. It's stored in a reasonably-plain-text-format in the table space. So if I (as an attacker) can get access to the disk, I'll just skip the logs and go right for the table information itself.

Now, if you're "hashing" the passwords in the database layer (meaning the plain-text password goes in the query, and the database issues the hash function), then you are correct that the logs may yield the plain-text password.

### It's not worth it

It's not worth trying to hide this information by flushing the logs. It's better to fix the problem from the source (use better hashing methods in your application).

The problem is that any hash that MySQL uses is a simple primitive hash (such as `MD5()` or `SHA256()`). Both are designed to be *fast*. So if I can get the hashed one from the table, I can attack it almost as easily as I can with a raw password. Why? Because fast hashes are easy to brute force [with GPUs](http://arstechnica.com/security/2012/12/25-gpu-cluster-cracks-every-standard-windows-password-in-6-hours/).

### TLDR

Basically, you have to do two things (from my point of view at least):

1. Keep people from getting access to the filesystem of the DB. This is first and formost.
2. Use proper password storage techniques (bcrypt, etc). This will mitigate any vector that log files may pose.

Comment: Thank you. I'm crypting passwords in php, using blowfish algorithm, and then pass them to my stored procedures through php pdo prepared statements. I'm concerned about the hashes being discovered, even though I use a technique where there's no foreign key hash/client + noise hashes so it is actually way harder to crack. Still, nothing is impossible so as you said I really have to keep people from getting access to the filesystem. I'm totally scared :-)

Comment: @Sebas: if that's the case (that you're using proper storage techniques), then don't worry about the logs. If an attacker can get the logs, they can get the raw table files. And they both have the same information. Instead, stop them from getting access to the filesystem. I wouldn't worry about the logs in that case...

Comment: Thank you for enlighting the problem.